# How to build several apks at once with custom gradle task?

Tags: android, gradle, apk, build.gradle

I'm struggling to find a way for build several apk at once with gradle.

I'd like to have a custom gradle task which considers only variants with `enviroment = "production"` and all the brands but `nonPublishedBrand` and `buildtype = "release"` (see code below).

For each of those variants i need to:

1. generate the signed apk
2. upload prodguard mappings to bugsnag with the relative task `uploadBugsnag${variant.name}-releaseMapping`
3. rename apk into `<brand>-<version>.apk` and move it to a common folder `$buildDir/myApks`

I only found a way to make assemble tasks also run my custom tasks but that's not ideal because i don't want to upload mappings every time a production release variant is built, but only when it's meant i.e. launching a specific gradle task.

Is it possible to achieve that with gradle? Can you please point me in the right direction?

See my build.gradle android section for reference:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1000000
    versionName "1.0.0.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}


signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("keystore/keystore")
        storePassword '*******'
        keyAlias '*******'
        keyPassword '*******'
    }
}

buildTypes {

    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        versionNameSuffix ".debug"
        manifestPlaceholders = [buildTypePrefix: "D_"]
    }

    release {
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        manifestPlaceholders = [buildTypePrefix: ""]
    }
}


flavorDimensions "environment", "brand"

productFlavors {
    //ENVIRONMENTS
    staging {
        dimension "environment"
        applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
        versionNameSuffix ".staging"
        buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://baseurl-staging.com\"")
        manifestPlaceholders = [environmentPrefix: "S_"]
    }

    production {
        dimension "environment"
        buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL"l, "\"http://baseurl-prod.com\"")
        manifestPlaceholders = [environmentPrefix: ""]
    }

    //BRANDS
    nonPublishedBrand {
        dimension "brand"
        applicationId "${packageBaseName}.nonpublishedbrand"
        manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Non published brand"]
        ext {
            facebook_app_id = [
                    staging: "0000000",
                    prod   : "11111111"
            ]
        }
    }


    brand1 {
        dimension "brand"
        applicationId "${packageBaseName}.brand1"
        manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Brand 1"]
        ext {
            facebook_app_id = [
                    staging: "22222222",
                    prod   : "33333333"
            ]
        }
    }

    brand2 {
        dimension "brand"
        applicationId "${packageBaseName}.brand2"
        manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "Brand 2"]
        ext {
            facebook_app_id = [
                    staging: "44444444",
                    prod   : "555555555"
            ]
        }
    }
}

productFlavors {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def isDebug = false
        if (variant.buildType.name == "debug") {
            isDebug = true
        }

        def isStaging = false
        def flavors = variant.productFlavors
        def environment = flavors[0]
        if (environment.name == "staging") {
            isStaging = true
        }

        def facebookAppId = ""
        if (isStaging){
            facebookAppId = flavors[1].facebook_app_id.staging
        }else{
            facebookAppId = flavors[1].facebook_app_id.prod
        }

        variant.buildConfigField "String", "FACEBOOK_APP_ID", "\"${facebookAppId}\""
    }
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}

bugsnag {
    autoUpload false
}
}
```

Comment: Try ./gradlew assemble

Comment: @Rockin `./gradlew assemble` generates all the apks in different folders, while I need only a subset of them (only release, production variants excluding `nonpublishedbrand`) in a common folder, renamed after uploading mapping files to bugsnag

Answer (score 0):

> **circle.ci** is an efficient way to generate builds with each commit.
>   Documentation : https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/

Your circle.yml file would have something like this :

```
    override:
        - ./gradlew clean :mobile:assemblePre -PdisablePreDex -Pandroid.threadPoolSize=1 -Dorg.gradle.parallel=false -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xms2048m -Xmx4608m"
        -  cp -r ~ build/outputs/apk/build/pre/*.apk  $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS

        - ./gradlew clean :mobile:assembleRelease -PdisablePreDex -Pandroid.threadPoolSize=1 -Dorg.gradle.parallel=false -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xms2048m -Xmx4608m"
        - cp -r ~build/outputs/apk/build/release/*.apk $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS
```

**assemblePre** and **assembleRelease** are tasks executed in above case. You can try to write custom tasks here.